# I Have entered the values of MNC,MCC,LAC and CID but the postman throws an error of CID should be less How to resolve this?

Tags: location, postman, here-api

I have entered the details given by the application as is but it throws this error.

**Postman request**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Details from the application**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: @Harsha, The error response is itself sufficient that Cid cant be greater than 65535.Please refer below link which say this too. https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/swagger/positioning-v1-external-spec.json

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/dev_guide/topics/error-response.html

Comment: I understood that but my Cid itself is shown above 665535 what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a Cell ID above 65536, probably because you're connected on a cell with technology different than GSM. For example, it could be an LTE cell.

I get a position estimate in Hyderabad with your MCC, MNC, CellID packed as follow:

```
{
  "lte": [{
    "mcc": 405,
    "mnc": 854,
    "cid": 33660944
  }]
}
```

The position estimate I get is:

```
{
    "location": {
        "lat": 17.4349916,
        "lng": 78.4345293,
        "accuracy": 2139
    }
}
```

Which is roughly **[there](https://www.google.com/maps/place/17%C2%B026'06.0%22N+78%C2%B026'04.3%22E/@17.4342756,78.2706238,10z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d17.435!4d78.4345278)**